# how to combine a toon shader a voronoi texture

Tags: materials, toon-shading

Currently, I'm trying to find a way to combine a toon shader and voronoi texture to create something like the example below, but I'm unaware of how to make this possible anyone know how I might achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the *Object* output of a *Texture Coordinate* node with a *Separate XYZ* node to generally create the black/white border in X, Y or Z direction depending on which separate output you choose.

The *Object* coordinates can be mixed with a *Voronoi Texture* by a *Mix RGB* node. And to finally get a pure black and white result I would put at a *Math* node set to *Greater Than* at the end.

To get your final desired look you can play around with the settings of the *Mix RGB* node, scale of the *Voronoi Texture*, the *Threshold* in the *Math* node (or switch it from *Greater Than* to *Less Than* maybe). Here's a quick example - in this case the mix factor is set to 1, which means it only uses the *Voronoi Texture* thus making the *Texture Coordinate* irrelevant. I chose this because I think it's closest to what you show in your question, but I'll leave the *Mix RGB* there so you can experiment with different settings:

[image: voronoi mix]

PS: You could also set the *Voronoi Texture* to *4D*, so that you can change the *W* value as a kind of seed to change the look. Also a *Mapping* node after the *Texture Coordinate* can be used to manipulate the orientation etc. of the original coordinates.

**//EDIT:** After your comment I suppose you're looking for something like this, although it's basically the same as before. I use a *Math* node (this time with *Less Than*) to create the general black/white mask and use it as mix between two colors. To get a third color, I just plug the resulting two into another mix node with a mix created by a different *Threshold* in the *Math* node. You could of course even use different *Voronoi Texture* nodes. The only crucial thing is creating the mask with a *Math* node.

[image: voronoi color mix]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my example was not entirely accurate to what I'm trying to do, I just couldn't think of a good way to visualize it. Here is a better example of what I'm trying to do [ https://imgur.com/a/8bKZHZB ]. (sorry again, I cannot seem to find a way to attach an image) 

 Basically, I'm attempting to create a toon shader that only shades the tiles generated from the voronoi texture.

Comment: @Dickhead_Jones Since you have a better example image, why don't you add this to the question? It's always better to have resources here instead of external sites.

Comment: @Dickhead_Jones I edited my answer to better fit your demands.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, and sorry for being an idiot.

Comment: @Dickhead_Jones Don't worry for being an idiot, I mean you have to live up to your nickname and that's okay :) Jokes aside, best way to thank on this site is accepting an answer if it solves your problem.